# Training of a CNN using Backpropagation

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, backpropagation

I have earlier worked in shallow(one or two layered) neural networks, so i have understanding of them, that how they work, and it is quite easy to visualize the derivations for forward and backward pass during the training of them, Currently I am studying about Deep neural networks(More precisely CNN), I have read lots of articles about their training, but still I am unable to understand the big picture of the training of the CNN, because in some cases people using pre- trained layers where convolution weights are extracted using auto-encoders, in some cases random weights were used for convolution, and then using back propagation they train the weights,  Can any one help me to give full picture of the training process from input to fully connected layer(Forward Pass) and from fully connected layer to input layer (Backward pass).

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend you a very good explanation of how to train a multilayer neural network using backpropagation. [This tutorial](http://peterroelants.github.io/posts/neural_network_implementation_part05/) is the 5th post of a very detailed explanation of how backpropagation works, and it also has Python examples of different types of neural nets to fully understand what's going on.

As a summary of Peter Roelants tutorial, I'll try to explain a little bit what is backpropagation.

As you have already said, there are two ways to initialize a deep NN: with random weights or pre-trained weights. In the case of random weights and for a supervised learning scenario, backpropagation works as following:

- Initialize your network parameters randomly.
- Feed forward a batch of labeled examples.
- Compute the error (given by your loss function) within the desired output and the actual one.
- Compute the partial derivative of the output error w.r.t each parameter.
- These derivatives are the gradients of the error w.r.t to the network's parameters. In other words, they are telling you how to change the value of the weights in order to get the desired output, instead of the produced one.
- Update the weights according to those gradients and the desired learning rate.
- Perform another forward pass with different training examples, repeat the following steps until the error stops decreasing.

Starting with random weights is not a problem for the backpropagation algorithm, given enough training data and iterations it will tune the weights until they work for the given task.

I really encourage you to follow the full tutorial I linked, because you'll get a very detalied view of how and why backpropagation works for multi layered neural networks.

Comment: Hey Thanks @gcucurull for your answer, actually i know how backpropagation algorithm works for multi layer network, I am  struggling with CNN; I want to know about how to train a CNN by using error of fully connected layer.

Comment: Well, the only difference is that in a CNN the weights are shared, so you also share the gradients and add them to update the shared weights. Check this link http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/machine-learning/convolutional-neural-networks/ where backpropagation for CNN is explained.

Comment: I have gone through the given link, i have read it earlier, if you will see in the link you will find that, author have described backpropagation for convolutional layers, it create confusion for me, that how error have been transferred to the convolutional layer from fully connected layer, and my question is mainly concern to this concept only.